# How to start a second media player ..?

Tags: java, android

I am developing an App where I want to play two mp3 files one is background music and another audio plays after 20 seconds.

```
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.testsong_20_sec); 
    mediaPlayer1 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.sound3 ); 
    private void buttonClick(){

    if (buttonPlayStop.getText() == getString(R.string.play_str)) {

    buttonPlayStop.setText(getString(R.string.pause_str));

    try
    {
    mediaPlayer.start();
    mediaPlayer1.start();

    startPlayProgressUpdater();
    }
    catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    mediaPlayer.pause();
    }

    }
```

Comment: what library are you using, can you provide us with some code.?

Comment: What is the nature of the other mp3 file? Short or long one?

Answer (score 0):

Use `MediaPlayer` to play background music and `SoundPool` for everything else.

Answer (score 0):

You can play two files in Mediaplayer by using this piece of code in a thread(don't use UI thread for this) :

```
mediaplayer = new MediaPlayer();

mediaplayer.reset();

//For media file 1

mediaplayer.setDataSource(dataSourceOne);

mediaplayer.prepare();

mediaplayer.start();

Thread.sleep(500);//Set the time as per your need.

//For media file 2

mediaplayer.reset();

mediaplayer.setDataSource(dataSourceTwo);


mediaplayer.setLooping(true);

mediaplayer.prepare();

mediaplayer.start();
```

As per the better implementation perspective, write an util class with all the common methods `(play(),pause(),stop())` and call every method from your class based on the requirement using a thread.